# how to keep header of content div fixed?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angularjs-ng-route

I have a web page built in angularjs .

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body ng-app="app1" ng-controller = "ctrl1">

<header></header>

<div ng-view></div>

<footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the header and footer is always fixed, but in content section when I am doing routing and in one of the view I have header which I always want to be fixed.

The problem is when use `position:fixed` for that content header and while moving the scroll of main page , the content below the header seems to move upwards.

so my question is how can I create that header in such a way that while scrolling down the content section or main section the header should always be fixed.[image]

Any help is appreciated  !!!

Thanks

Comment: So in the ng-view, you also want to have another header with position:fixed ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: I believe that @nikjohn answer solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

WHat you need to do is add a `padding-top` to you content that is equal to the height of your header. That way your content will never scroll up below the header

```
.content-header {
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}
.content-container {
padding-top: 30px;
overflow: scroll;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: should we put the position:relative into .content-container ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. That needs to be added for the position: absolute to work. Will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use     `overflow: scroll;` for that div.

```
<div class="content" ng-view></data>

.content {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Refer : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Reference: [the 'overflow' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap to ease your task.
Kindly refer to :
 https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Hope this helps you.